# Is it possible to pass a string to dialog() in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a question about the `dialog()` function of Jquery.
I  wonder if instead using it with  an selector before it, like this

```
$('#dialog').dialog(open)
....

  <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
   <p>Dialog Test</p>
  </div>
```

if I could pass the `"<p>Dialog Test</p>"` to it as a pure string in some way ?

Best wishes

Comment: Why don't you try it and see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $('<p></p>').dialog({
        autoOpen:true,
        show: "fold",
        hide: "explode",
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        height: 135,
        width: 400,
        title: 'Dialog test',
        buttons:{
            "Ok":function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close:function(){
            //$(this).dialog("destroy");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call it like

```
$("<p>Dialog Test</p>").dialog({

         modal: true,

         buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }       

        });
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/F973e/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    'title' : 'Dialog Title'
});
```

This will create the dialog, assign the title, and auto-open. To open manually, se auto-open to `false`, then call `open` later:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    'title' : 'Dialog Title',
    'autoOpen' : false
});

// ...

$('#dialog').dialog('open');
```

Comment: In my version of ui, this adds the text "I'm a dialog" to the dialog. Badness. Surprised there's no :content option.